# How to apply a function to selected rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a `regex` function to selected rows in a dataframe. My solution works but the code is terribly long and I wonder if there is not a better, faster and more elegant way to solve this problem.

In words I want my regex function to be applied to elements of the `source_value` column, but only to rows where the column `source_type` == `rhombus` AND (`rhombus_refer_to_odk_type` == `integer` OR a `decimal`).

The code:

```
df_arrows.loc[(df_arrows['source_type']=='rhombus') & ((df_arrows['rhombus_refer_to_odk_type']=='integer') | (df_arrows['rhombus_refer_to_odk_type']=='decimal')),'source_value'] = df_arrows.loc[(df_arrows['source_type']=='rhombus') & ((df_arrows['rhombus_refer_to_odk_type']=='integer') | (df_arrows['rhombus_refer_to_odk_type']=='decimal')),'source_value'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'^[^<=>]+','', str(x)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with condition in variable `m` and for replace use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
m = (df_arrows['source_type']=='rhombus') & 
     df_arrows['rhombus_refer_to_odk_type'].isin(['integer','decimal'])
df_arrows.loc[m,'source_value'] = df_arrows.loc[m,'source_value'].astype(str).str.replace(r'^[^<=>]+','')
```

EDIT: If mask is 2 dimensional possible problem should be duplicated columns names, you can test it:

```
 print ((df_arrows['source_type']=='rhombus'))
 print (df_arrows['rhombus_refer_to_odk_type'].isin(['integer','decimal']))
```

Comment: Great! And you got rid of the `apply`. Just one minor issue: that in your `df_arrows.loc` the `m` is 2dimensional and leads to the error 'Cannot index with multidimensional key'. I have replaced it with `df_arrows.loc[m.index,'source_value']`

Comment: @Aneho - it is weird, `df_arrows['source_type']=='rhombus')` return 2 columns mask? Or `df_arrows['rhombus_refer_to_odk_type'].isin(['integer','decimal'])` ?

Comment: You are right, I had a mistake and applied the first term to `df_arrows`. I was writing `m = df_arrows[(df_arrows['source_type']=='rhombus') & ....] 
So you first suggestion was correct. Thank you again.